# What is the use of "laravel_session" cookie?

Tags: laravel, cookies

So i have created a project and right now i have to give information about every cookie that it is used. I am using laravel 5.0 and the cookies that are used by laravel are the below :

```
1) laravel_session
2) XSRF-TOKEN
```

I know about the second one, but i can't find information about the first one. Is it about knowing the current user? The project also uses socialite - facebook.

Please, if you need any further information feel free to ask and i will provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Internally laravel uses laravel_session to identify a session instance for a user, this can be changed by going into `config/session.php` and editing the `cookie` value

Comment: So, every user has a laravel_session so it can be used as an ID session and refer to that user?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos everytime a new session cookie is created it uses that id. Yes every user will have that cookie.